# Запуск jar без MANIFEST.MF

Tags: java, консоль, jar

Как запустить jar архив с рабочими классами внутри без manifest.mf через консоль windows?

Comment: Странноватый вопрос, но ты попробуй извлечь данные с `.jar` файла в определенную папку, а дальше с помощью консоли запусти `Main.class` только вот в консоли `.class` писать не надо, просто его имя `Main` или что там у тебя)

Comment: У меня 3 класса и 1 интерфейс. Задание: запихнуть руками в jar и запустить из консоли без Manifest.mf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Взято с [английского СО](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474666/how-to-run-a-class-from-jar-which-is-not-the-main-class-in-its-manifest-file):

```
java -cp MyJar.jar com.mycomp.MainClass /home/myhome/datasource.properties /home/myhome/input.txt
```

`MyJar.jar` - собственно имя вашего JAR файла

`com.mycomp.MainClass` - полное имя вашего класса(с пакетом)

`/home/myhome/datasource.properties /home/myhome/input.txt` - параметры которые передадутся в метод `main(String ... args)`